# JSONPath Filter doesn't work for non similar nodes

Tags: json

I'm using this tool - https://jsonpath.com/

Here is my JSON

```
{
   "book":[
      {
         "fictionBook":{
            "id":"444",
            "language":"C",
            "edition":"First",
            "author":"Dennis Ritchie "
         }
      },
      {
         "non-fictionBook":{
            "id":"555",
            "language":"C++",
            "edition":"second",
            "author":" Bjarne Stroustrup "
         }
      },
      {
         "non-fictionBook":{
            "id":"666",
            "language":"D++",
            "edition":"second",
            "author":" Bjarne Stroustrup "
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the JSONPath - $.book[*].*.[?(@.id == "555")], this doesn't bring me matches, how can i solve this. I know JSON is little bit weird

Here is the JSONPath - $.book[*].*.[?(@.id == "555")], this doesn't bring me matches, how can i solve this. I know JSON is little bit weird